# Gruntjs: can I share the "auth" section amongst different ftpush tasks?

Tags: javascript, json, deployment, ftp, gruntjs

I have a task in my Gruntfile which pushes changed files to my server over ftp. The tasks all use the same authentication, and I would like to remove all the duplicate "auth" parts and define it just once.

The current working version (which contains a lot of duplicates) looks like this (shortened for readability):

```
ftpush: {
  css_prod: {
    auth: {
      host: 'xxx.xx.xx.x',
      port: 21,
      authKey: 'authKey'
    },
    src: '<%= dirs.dev_css_build %>',
    dest: '<%= dirs.prod_css %>',
    simple: true,
    useList: false
  },
  css_wordpress: {
    auth: {
      host: 'xxx.xx.xx.x',
      port: 21,
      authKey: 'authKey'
    },
    src: '<%= dirs.dev_css %>/style.css',
    dest: '<%= dirs.prod_theme_current %>',
    simple: true,
    useList: false
  },
  js_standalone: {
    auth: {
      host: 'xxx.xx.xx.x',
      port: 21,
      authKey: 'authKey'
    },
    src: '<%= dirs.dev_js_standalone %>',
    dest: '<%= dirs.prod_js_standalone %>',
    simple: false,
    useList: false
  }
}
```

I've tried defining the "auth" part in an "options" area, like so:

```
ftpush: {
  options: {
    auth: {
      host: 'xxx.xx.xx.x',
      port: 21,
      authKey: 'authKey'
    }      
  },
  css_prod: {
    src: '<%= dirs.dev_css_build %>',
    dest: '<%= dirs.prod_css %>',
    simple: true,
    useList: false
  },
  css_wordpress: {
    src: '<%= dirs.dev_css %>/style.css',
    dest: '<%= dirs.prod_theme_current %>',
    simple: true,
    useList: false
  },
  js_standalone: {
    src: '<%= dirs.dev_js_standalone %>',
    dest: '<%= dirs.prod_js_standalone %>',
    simple: false,
    useList: false
  }
}
```

But that does not work. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a perfect solution, but you can use grunt config templating to reference the real values defined in only one place.

For example you can try to make your second solution working with adding the next line to each "real" sections:

```
auth: '<%= ftpush.options.auth %>'
```

And this way the auth section will be inserted to all subsections.

Comment: Ah, yeah that's a nice solution as well. Hopefully someone knows of a ftpush native solution that works without adding the `auth:` line to every task. But if that's not possible then this is the next best thing.